# Multiple conditions in a when statement

Tags: kotlin

I have a sealed class

```
sealed class Sealed {
   data class dataA()
   data class dataB()
   data class dataC()
}
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
when(val someDate = functionReturningSealedClassData){
   is Sealed.dataA -> { whatever() }
   is Sealed.dataB -> { whatever() }
   else -> { somethingElse() }
}
```

I'd now like to know whether I can condense this is ...dataA and  is ...dataB together into one thing. Can't find it in the kotlin documentation on how to do this. Any hints? It's not a range after all, or something like that...

Answer (score 3):

Ah, simple:

```
when(val someDate = functionReturningSealedClassData){
   is Sealed.dataA, is Sealed.dataB -> { whatever() }
   else -> { somethingElse() }
}
```